# How to use Joomlas {loadmodule}

Tags: joomla, loadmodule

Can somebody please provide an example how to use joomlas build in {loadmodule} feature to load a custom html module. According to the docs at [http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article?)
it should be something like
{loadmodule Custom HTML,My module title}
But it does not work that way...
{loadposition} works perfectly. I'm on joomla 3.2.1 btw.

Comment: What does it do? Does it not render at all or something else/

Comment: It does not render at all. I have a custom html module containing some schema.org microdata. I'm using it like: {loadmodule Custom HTML,Schema Organization DE} Using loadposition instead of loadmodule is working well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the name and cases match exactly including spaces. These are examples from the learn joomla sample data.

```
{loadmodule articles_archive,Archived Articles}
{loadmodule> custom,Custom HTML}
```

Notice that the exact title goes second.

Comment: You tried it with the correct name (custom)?   Because you code in the question is using the wrong name.  Can you please paste exactly what you have?

Comment: {loadmodule custom,Schema Organization DE} I even copy&pasted the module title just to be certain there's no typo in it. But nothing is showing up.

Comment: Do you have it set to display on all pages or on that specific page?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments:

1. Your module type is Custom HTML, i.e. mod_custom
2. The title of your module is "Schema Organization DE"

Therefore, as @Elin, has said your `loadmodule` tag should be

```
{loadmodule custom,Schema Organization DE}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, unfortunately nothing is showing up... Maybe there's a little detail missing in {loadmodule custom,Schema Organization DE} or maybe something is broken. I'm using Joomla 3.2.2 btw. Any ideas?

Comment: Well if it's published I'm stumped. Can you add the raw html content of the module to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{loadmodule mod_custom,Schema Organization DE}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to not to render a specific module, but to render a custom module position like this:
{loadposition my_custom_position}, then go to Extensions > Module manager and published your desires module on my_custom_position

Hope that helps!

Comment: People use loadmodule when they want one specific module. Admittedly most of the time it would be something like a menu being included in a custom template index file. But this is valid.

Answer (score 0):

content plugin loads Module positions, Syntax: {loadposition user1} or Modules by name, Syntax: {loadmodule mod_login}. Optionally can specify module style and for loadmodule a specific module by title, Syntax: {loadmodule mod_login,module title,style}.

Make sure the menu assignment for the module set to the respective pages.